# mySQL to GCP Cloud-Storage

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, google-cloud-platform

I created the code below in order to transfer all tables from my mySQL to Cloud-Storage as JSON files. It worked for small tables but once I try this on different (bigger) tables I get errors like this:

```
Loading Table copy_data.csv
UserWarning: `read_sql_table` defaulting to pandas implementation.
Killed
root@e384bbce5322:/home/python2# /usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 24 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#mysql to bigquery (all tables)


import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq as pd_gbq
import modin.pandas as pd_mod
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import csv
# Service account file for GCP connection
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('key.json')
#  BigQuery Variables
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/home/python2/key.json"
#  MySql Variables
MYSQL_USERNAME = 'root'
MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'password!'
MYSQL_HOST = 'localhost'
MYSQL_DATABASE = 'test'
# Path for the dump directory
DIRECTORY = 'dump'

  
def main():

    con_uri = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
        MYSQL_USERNAME,
        MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        MYSQL_HOST,
        MYSQL_DATABASE
    )
    print('Connection url {}'.format(con_uri))

    try:
        engine = create_engine(con_uri, pool_recycle=3600).connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error {}'.format(e))

    tables_query = 'SELECT table_name ' \
                   'FROM information_schema.tables ' \
                   'WHERE TABLE_TYPE = "BASE TABLE" ' \
                   'AND TABLE_SCHEMA = "{}";'.format(MYSQL_DATABASE)

    list_tables = pd.read_sql(tables_query, con_uri)

    for index, row in list_tables.iterrows():
        table_id = '{}.{}'.format(DATASET_ID, row['table_name'])
        print("*******************************")

        print('Loading Table {}'.format(table_id))
        df = pd_mod.read_sql_table(row['table_name'], engine)
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("my-buckets-123")
        blob = bucket.blob("{}.json".format(row['table_name']))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=df).to_json(orient='records')
        #df = pd.DataFrame(data=myresult).to_csv(sep=";", index=False, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding="UTF-8")
        blob.upload_from_string(data=df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I read about this error and it seems like since this table is too large for the RAM , how can I deal with this? can I fix this code? maybe read in chunks?

Please help :)

Comment: You can certainly break it into chunks using LIMIT and OFFSET (making sure its sorted), but how big are these tables?  This isn't very efficient.

Comment: currently i have only 2 tables , one is with 100 rows and the other is with 1.8mil (about 700mb size). what's better efficient way doing it?

Comment: One example, if you have enough access, to use mysqldump directly to output to csvs. (Examples here: https://electrictoolbox.com/using-mysqldump-to-save-data-to-csv-files/)

Comment: is it the same like using this: SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id',id) from test
? or CSV with sqldump is faster?