# mySQL to GCP Cloud-storage slowness

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-platform

I made this code to copy all tables from mySQL to json files in GCP Cloud-Storage.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#mysql to bigquery (all tables)


import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq as pd_gbq
import modin.pandas as pd_mod
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import csv
# Service account file for GCP connection
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('key.json')
#  BigQuery Variables
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/home/python2/key.json"
#  MySql Variables
MYSQL_USERNAME = 'root'
MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'password!'
MYSQL_HOST = 'localhost'
MYSQL_DATABASE = 'test'
# Path for the dump directory
DIRECTORY = 'dump'

  
def main():

    con_uri = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
        MYSQL_USERNAME,
        MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        MYSQL_HOST,
        MYSQL_DATABASE
    )
    print('Connection url {}'.format(con_uri))

    try:
        engine = create_engine(con_uri, pool_recycle=3600).connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error {}'.format(e))

    tables_query = 'SELECT table_name ' \
                   'FROM information_schema.tables ' \
                   'WHERE TABLE_TYPE = "BASE TABLE" ' \
                   'AND TABLE_SCHEMA = "{}";'.format(MYSQL_DATABASE)

    list_tables = pd.read_sql(tables_query, con_uri)

    for index, row in list_tables.iterrows():
        table_id = '{}.{}'.format(DATASET_ID, row['table_name'])
        print("*******************************")

        print('Loading Table {}'.format(table_id))
        df = pd_mod.read_sql_table(row['table_name'], engine)
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("my-buckets-123")
        blob = bucket.blob("{}.json".format(row['table_name']))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=df).to_json(orient='records')
        #df = pd.DataFrame(data=myresult).to_csv(sep=";", index=False, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding="UTF-8")
        blob.upload_from_string(data=df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It works but really slow, currently I have only 2 tables with size of 30-40MB but it doesn't seems like it's working in parallel to do it faster.
I also get those warnings when running the script:

```
UserWarning: Dask execution environment not yet initialized. Initializing...
To remove this warning, run the following python code before doing dataframe operations:

    from distributed import Client

    client = Client()
UserWarning: `read_sql_table` defaulting to pandas implementation.
```

What am i doing wrong? how can I fix this code to work in parallel / faster? is it possible to do it in chunks?

Comment: Which is the main sluggishness -- Reading the rows?  Converting to JSON?  Sending across the network?  (You may be surprised in the answer.  It will give you a clue of what ot focus on.)

Comment: ```        df = pd_mod.read_sql_table(row['table_name'], engine)
```
This one is making troubles. it's slow and sometimes on big tables the script is being Killed.

Comment: How big is the table (rows or GB)?

Comment: You might want to improve your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70668185/3399890) rather than posting nearly identical questions multiple times.

Comment: it's about 1mil rows and 400MB. not that big at all to be honest. i wonder if it's something with my code or because the mySQL is running on slow machine